# Laravel saving HasOne creates duplicate entries

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.6

When attempting to update my properties model and hasOne address relationship, I keep on getting duplicate rows in my data.
I'm not expecting an insert / update as the data is exactly the same.

I'm not having issues with creating or updated the property model.

**Issue Code**

```
     // save address relation
     $address = new PropertyAddress($propertyDetails['address']);
     $property->address()->save($address);
```

**Property Model**

Fields: id, ........

> $this->hasOne('App\Models\Property\PropertyAddress');

**PropertyAddress Model**

Fields: id, property_id, ......

> $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Property\Property');

**Controller**

```
    $property = Property::with('address')->firstOrNew(
       ['agency_id' => $propertyDetails['agency_id'], 'external_ref' => $propertyDetails['external_ref'] ]
     );

     $property->fill($propertyDetails);
     $property->save();

     // save address relation
     $address = new PropertyAddress($propertyDetails['address']);
     $property->address()->save($address);
```

[image: Duplicate address relations]

Comment: Try mentioning the foreign key `$this->hasOne('App\Models\Property\PropertyAddress', 'property_id');`

Comment: @linuxartisan I've already tried that for both models and still having same issue:

  `$this->hasOne('App\Models\Property\PropertyAddress', 'property_id', 'id');`
and
   `$this->belongsTo('App\Models\Property\Property', 'id', 'property_id');`